# Configuring collapseComponent in apachesolr

Tags: classnotfoundexception, solr

I have applied the collapsecomponent patch to solr 3.1.0

My question is , how do I configure it in solrconfig.xml?
What needs to be added.

Right now I have added the following and its giving me a classnotfound exception for the collapsecomponent class: http://pastebin.com/S6AQiVq1

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the class to solrconfig:

```
<searchComponent name="collapse" class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.CollapseComponent">
```